# Django - Group by column and where on a different column

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

These are my django models (simplified):

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForiegnKey(Client)

class TicketRequest(models.Model):
    status = models.ForiegnKey(Status, related_name='ticket_requests')
    project = models.ForiegnKey(Project)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

#### Required result

```
status.value  |  client.id  |  count
--------------+-------------+---------
is_assigned   |           4 |      2
is_closed     |           4 |      66
is_open       |           4 |      7
```

#### Queryset annotate

```
Status.objects.filter(
    ticket_requests__project__client_id=4
).values('value').annotate(
    count=Count('ticket_requests__project__client')
)
```

returns

```
[{'count': 2, 'value': u'is_assigned'}, {'count': 66, 'value': u'is_closed'}, {'count': 7, 'value': u'is_open'}]
```

which is exactly what is required.

*But I need to filter the queryset on `TicketRequest.created`with filters such as today, this week and month.*

Since these filters need to be reused a lot, I created a handy helper:

```
def qs_time_range(qs, time_range, field_name):
    now = timezone.now()

    if time_range == 'month':
        past = now - timedelta(days=30)

    return qs.filter(
        **{field_name + '__date__range': [past, now]}
    )
```

#### Problem

When I use the helper to filter the ticket requests, the results are not what I expect.

```
data = filters.qs_time_range(
    Status.objects.filter(ticket_requests__project__client_id=4), 
    'month', 
    'ticket_requests__created'
).values('value').annotate(
    count=Count('ticket_requests__project__client')
)
```

Result

```
[{'count': 27, 'value': u'is_assigned'}]
```

When instead this should have been the result:

```
[{'count': 3, 'value': u'is_assigned'}, {'count': 3, 'value': u'is_closed'}, {'count': 3, 'value': u'is_open'}]
```

**Question**: Is the filtering messing up the SQL? What should I try instead?

---

#### Additional Info - Raw SQL

`data.query` reveals this SQL (modified for Postgres)

```
SELECT "tickets_status"."value",
       COUNT("projects_project"."client_id") AS "count"
FROM "tickets_status"
INNER JOIN "tickets_ticketrequest" ON ("tickets_status"."id" = "tickets_ticketrequest"."status_id")
INNER JOIN "projects_project" ON ("tickets_ticketrequest"."project_id" = "projects_project"."id")
INNER JOIN "tickets_ticketrequest" T5 ON ("tickets_status"."id" = T5."status_id")
WHERE ("projects_project"."client_id" = 4
       AND T5."created"::date BETWEEN '2016-09-02' AND '2016-10-02')
GROUP BY "tickets_status"."value",
         "tickets_status"."name"
ORDER BY "tickets_status"."name" ASC;
```

which returns

```
    value    | count 
-------------+-------
 is_assigned |    27
(1 row)
```

But this is the SQL that I want generated:

```
SELECT "tickets_status"."value",
       COUNT("projects_project"."client_id") AS "count"
FROM "tickets_status"
INNER JOIN "tickets_ticketrequest" ON ("tickets_status"."id" = "tickets_ticketrequest"."status_id")
INNER JOIN "projects_project" ON ("tickets_ticketrequest"."project_id" = "projects_project"."id")
WHERE ("projects_project"."client_id" = 4
        AND "tickets_ticketrequest"."created"::date BETWEEN '2016-09-02' AND '2016-10-02')
GROUP BY "tickets_status"."value",
         "tickets_status"."name"
ORDER BY "tickets_status"."name" ASC;
```

which returns the **right result**

```
    value    | count 
-------------+-------
 is_assigned |     3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: First of all have to state the obvious: are you sure you have any closed or open ticket requests created in the last month? That would be the most obvious cause. But if you already double- and triple-checked that, then I have a vague memory of having a similar problem somewhere, but can't remember why. But I fixed it by changing `Count()` to `Sum(Case(When(set__the__condition='set_the_value'), then=1), default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField()))`.

Comment: @makaveli have added the SQL statements generated by the query to the question.

Comment: @makaveli I don't understand that statement with Sum, Case and When. I tried `values('value').annotate(Sum(Case(When('ticket_requests__project__client'), then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField()))` but got `TypeError`, probably because I passed the field (to group by) instead of the lookup.

Comment: @makaveli Success!!. This worked: `statuses.values('value').annotate(count=models.Count(models.Case(models.When(ticket_requests__project__client_id=4, then=1))))`. Do add your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lovely to hear that you got your stuff working, but this answer is 1 explanation short of a reasoning behind this magic. I remembered that this works, but if someone comes up with an explanation WHY it works, then that is the real correct answer. But yeah, if `django.db.models.Count` doesn't work as expected, you can replace it with a combination of `Sum(Case(When(field='value'), then=1), default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField())` (in Django >= 1.9).

The original comment that solved the problem:

> First of all have to state the obvious: are you sure you have any
>   closed or open ticket requests created in the last month? That would
>   be the most obvious cause. But if you already double- and
>   triple-checked that, then I have a vague memory of having a similar
>   problem somewhere, but can't remember why. But I fixed it by changing
>   Count() to Sum(Case(When(set__the__condition='set_the_value'),
>   then=1), default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField())).